# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric in my select column list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have an table where i would insert the records from one table to another
like

```
insert into dbo.table1 (col1,col2,col3)
select col1,col2,col3
from  table2
```

I was not able to insert the records from the table2 into the table1,table 2 having issue,

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

while I dig all the way in the table2 there are two fieles where I could find the different data types, I have changed as compared to the source table, but still find the same issue.

In my table2 all the fields having issue, its showing the same error message (
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric), when I select the single column in the select list same error, multiple columns in the select list same error, data also looks almost identical in both the tables.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: SQL server 2012

Comment: Please read the guidelines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: _I could find the different data types, I have changed as compared to the source table_ - can you please post the table definitions of both tables? (or at least the data types of all columns)

Comment: data types previously numeric and nvarchar, i have changed the Nvarchar to numeric datatypes both looks same

Comment: Do you have special characters in the fields name (like `§`)? I used to have the same problem and it was the name of the fields. In that case or you change the names or the collate (both thing can have serius implications!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try_convert()`.  I don't know what the destination columns are, but something like this:

```
insert into dbo.table1 (col1, col2, col3)
    select try_convert(numeric(38, 6), col1),
           try_convert(numeric(38, 6), col2), 
           try_convert(numeric(38, 6), col3)
    from table2;
```

That said, you might want to find the offending values:

```
select col1
from table2
where try_convert(numeric(38, 6), col1) is null and col1 is not null;
```

Then fix the data!

Comment: @NareshYadala . . . `try_convert()` *cannot* generate a type conversion error.  If you are still getting that error, then that suggests that you have a trigger on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I would request you to find the difference in metadata of two tables first

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUM_NAME IN () 
AND TABLE_NAME =''table1'
EXCEPT 
SELECT DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUM_NAME IN () 
AND TABLE_NAME =''table2'
```

Comment: Can you drop table1 and execute below query?       Select col1, col2, col3 into table1 from table2